# AMD Driver Install Troubleshooting

Tags: 12.10, drivers, ati, 64-bit

I have an ATI 5670 HD. I'm running ubuntu 12.10 64bit. I've been having a hell of a time trying to install the most recent drivers for my video card. Everything else seems to be working with the exception of the video card. It's a fresh install on a new partition.

I followed the instructions to the letter here: http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide

And my card is definitely supported by the drivers, I know this for certain because in another partition I have a 32 bit system where both Catalyst 13.1 and 13.2 work flawlessly:

```
sudo lshw -C video
PCI (sysfs)  

  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Redwood [Radeon HD 5670]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fbee0000-fbefffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fbec0000-fbedffff
```

Then I tried using this tool (which essentially duplicates the instructions on the guide): http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/ubuntu-amd-catalyst-install

What I end up with is always the same, regardless of which drivers (13.1,13.2) I install on the system.

```
$ fglrxinfo 
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (ATIFGLEXTENSION)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  66 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  13
  Current serial number in output stream:  13
```

I've tracked what I believe to be the problem during the manual install process:

```
(Reading database ... 198845 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace fglrx 2:9.000-0ubuntu3 (using fglrx_12.100-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking replacement fglrx ...
Preparing to replace fglrx-amdcccle 2:8.970-0ubuntu1 (using fglrx-amdcccle_12.100-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement fglrx-amdcccle ...
Preparing to replace fglrx-dev 2:8.970-0ubuntu1 (using fglrx-dev_12.100-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement fglrx-dev ...
Setting up fglrx (2:12.100-0ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf because link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf because link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Loading new fglrx-12.100 DKMS files...
Building only for 3.5.0-17-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Setting up fglrx-amdcccle (2:12.100-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up fglrx-dev (2:12.100-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
```

The part where is says "update alternative" does not present itself during the duplicated installation process on my 32bit Ubuntu install on the same computer:

```
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf because link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken
```

Comment: Possibly related: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2073198

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to get it up and running by repeating the initial process (either the app from fan club or the instructions on the page above):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

I'm not sure which of the three was the one that "did" it, but after they were installed I was able to successfully go through the process.

Comment: Confirmed, worked for me; 12.10 64-bit, ASRock motherboard, AMD processor, 7950 card. Did have to restart though.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I already had the linux-headers-* installed, but not the source.